# libsass inspect, str_index

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, libsass

I have the following code that works well under sass 3.4.14

```
@function replaceAttribute($xml, $insert, $attribute) {
@if type-of($insert) != string {
    $insert: inspect($insert);
}
$search_str: $attribute + '="';

//How much to add to get to where the string should be inserted
$offset: str_length($search_str);
$idx: 1;
//The next attribute to replace in string
$next: str_index($xml, $search_str);

@while $next != null {
    $idx: $idx + $offset + $next - 1;

    //Remove old attribute value and add new
    $length_next: str_index(str_slice($xml, $idx), '"');
    $xml: str_slice($xml, 0, $idx - 1) + str_slice($xml, $idx + $length_next - 1);
    $xml: str_insert($xml, $insert, $idx);

    //Find new next attribute to replace
    $next: str_index(str_slice($xml, $idx), $search_str);
}
@return $xml;
}
```

It doesn't work well using libsass 3.2 but according to sass-compatibility.github.io/ all the string functions used here should be supported. 
I get the following error message:

argument `$insert` of `str-insert($string, $insert, $index)` must be a string

How do I fix this? I am trying to switch to libsass for reasons of sass compile time.

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce a problem.  We need to be able to see what you're passing to this function to cause the error.

Comment: Sorry about not answering, fixed it and got excited and got on with other things, turns out inspect() doesn't convert things of type color (as in color: white; e.g.) to strings. Fixed it by changing someone else's hardcoded color into '#fff'. That's weird.